# MySQL Out Of Memory

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been facing this error lot of times, every time I face this error I used to restart the mysql service from **services.msc**

```
    2021-07-04T05:45:24.015235Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory (Needed 3657330108 bytes)
    2021-07-04T05:45:24.017510Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
    2021-07-04T05:45:24.036153Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory (Needed 3657330108 bytes)
    2021-07-04T05:45:24.036861Z 4 [ERROR] [MY-010934] [Server] Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
    05:45:24 UTC - mysqld got exception 0xc0000005 ;
    Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Thread pointer: 0x2126ca2baf0
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    
    MySQL Workbench: 8.0
    OS: Windows Server 64 bit, 4 GB RAM

Please advise ahead how to resolve the issue and how to configure my.ini
```

Please find below my.ini file configuration.

```
# Other default tuning values
# MySQL Server Instance Configuration File
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated by the MySQL Server Instance Configuration Wizard
#
#
# Installation Instructions
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# On Linux you can copy this file to /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options
# (@localstatedir@ for this installation) or to
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# On Windows you should keep this file in the installation directory 
# of your server (e.g. C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y). To
# make sure the server reads the config file use the startup option 
# "--defaults-file". 
#
# To run the server from the command line, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# To install the server as a Windows service manually, execute this in a 
# command line shell, e.g.
# mysqld --install MySQLXY --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server X.Y\my.ini"
#
# And then execute this in a command line shell to start the server, e.g.
# net start MySQLXY
#
#
# Guidelines for editing this file
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that the program supports.
# If you want to know the options a program supports, start the program
# with the "--help" option.
#
# More detailed information about the individual options can also be
# found in the manual.
#
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
#
#
# CLIENT SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by MySQL client applications.
# Note that only client applications shipped by MySQL are guaranteed
# to read this section. If you want your own MySQL client program to
# honor these values, you need to specify it as an option during the
# MySQL client library initialization.
#
[client]

# pipe=

# socket=MYSQL

port=3306

[mysql]
no-beep

# default-character-set=

# SERVER SECTION
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# The following options will be read by the MySQL Server. Make sure that
# you have installed the server correctly (see above) so it reads this 
# file.
#
# server_type=3
[mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# shared-memory

# shared-memory-base-name=MYSQL

# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=MYSQL

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
# basedir="C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/"

# Path to the database root
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data

# The default character set that will be used when a new schema or table is
# created and no character set is defined
# character-set-server=

# The default authentication plugin to be used when connecting to the server
default_authentication_plugin=caching_sha2_password

# The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables when
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# General and Slow logging.
log-output=FILE

general-log=0

general_log_file="EC2AMAZ-E5C84BA.log"

slow-query-log=1

slow_query_log_file="EC2AMAZ-E5C84BA-slow.log"

long_query_time=10

# Error Logging.
log-error="EC2AMAZ-E5C84BA.err"

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Specifies the base name to use for binary log files. With binary logging
# enabled, the server logs all statements that change data to the binary
# log, which is used for backup and replication.
log-bin="EC2AMAZ-E5C84BA-bin"

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Sets the binary logging format, and can be any one of STATEMENT, ROW,
# or MIXED. ROW is suggested for Group Replication.
# binlog_format

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Causes the master to write a checksum for each event in the binary log.
# binlog_checksum supports the values NONE (disabled) and CRC32.
# The default is CRC32. When disabled (value NONE), the server verifies
# that it is writing only complete events to the binary log by writing
# and checking the event length (rather than a checksum) for each event.
# NONE must be used with Group Replication.
# binlog_checksum

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# The base name for the relay log. The server creates relay log files in
# sequence by adding a numeric suffix to the base name. If you specify this
# option, the value specified is also used as the base name for the relay log
# index file. Relay logs increase speed by using load-balancing between disks.
# relay_log

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Specifies the server ID. For servers that are used in a replication topology,
# you must specify a unique server ID for each replication server, in the
# range from 1 to 2^32 − 1. “Unique” means that each ID must be different
# from every other ID in use by any other replication master or slave.
server-id=1

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# The host name or IP address of the slave to be reported to the master
# during slave registration. This value appears in the output of SHOW SLAVE HOSTS
# on the master server. Leave the value unset if you do not want the slave to
# register itself with the master.
# report_host=0.0

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# The TCP/IP port number for connecting to the slave, to be reported to the master during
# slave registration. Set this only if the slave is listening on a nondefault port or if
# you have a special tunnel from the master or other clients to the slave.
report_port=3306

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# This option specifies whether global transaction identifiers (GTIDs) are
# used to identify transactions. ON must be used with Group Replication.
# gtid_mode

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# When enabled, the server enforces GTID consistency by allowing execution of
# only statements that can be safely logged using a GTID. You must set this
# option to ON before enabling GTID based replication.
# enforce_gtid_consistency

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Whether updates received by a slave server from a master server should be
# logged to the slave's own binary log. Binary logging must be enabled on
# the slave for this variable to have any effect. ON must be used with
# Group Replication.
# log_slave_updates

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Determines whether the slave server logs master status and connection information
# to an InnoDB table in the mysql database, or to a file in the data directory.
# The TABLE setting is required when multiple replication channels are configured.
# master_info_repository

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Determines whether the slave server logs its position in the relay logs to an InnoDB
# table in the mysql database, or to a file in the data directory. The TABLE setting is
# required when multiple replication channels are configured.
# relay_log_info_repository

# ***** Group Replication Related *****
# Defines the algorithm used to hash the writes extracted during a transaction. If you
# are using Group Replication, this variable must be set to XXHASH64 because the process
# of extracting the writes from a transaction is required for conflict detection on all
# group members.
# transaction_write_set_extraction

# NOTE: Modify this value after Server initialization won't take effect.
lower_case_table_names=1

# Secure File Priv.
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"

# The maximum amount of concurrent sessions the MySQL server will
# allow. One of these connections will be reserved for a user with
# SUPER privileges to allow the administrator to login even if the
# connection limit has been reached.
max_connections=151

# The number of open tables for all threads. Increasing this value
# increases the number of file descriptors that mysqld requires.
# Therefore you have to make sure to set the amount of open files
# allowed to at least 4096 in the variable "open-files-limit" in
# section [mysqld_safe]
table_open_cache=2000

# Maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables. If a table
# grows larger than this value, it is automatically converted to disk
# based table This limitation is for a single table. There can be many
# of them.
tmp_table_size=64M

# How many threads we should keep in a cache for reuse. When a client
# disconnects, the client's threads are put in the cache if there aren't
# more than thread_cache_size threads from before.  This greatly reduces
# the amount of thread creations needed if you have a lot of new
# connections. (Normally this doesn't give a notable performance
# improvement if you have a good thread implementation.)
thread_cache_size=10

#*** MyISAM Specific options
# The maximum size of the temporary file MySQL is allowed to use while
# recreating the index (during REPAIR, ALTER TABLE or LOAD DATA INFILE.
# If the file-size would be bigger than this, the index will be created
# through the key cache (which is slower).
myisam_max_sort_file_size=6G

# If the temporary file used for fast index creation would be bigger
# than using the key cache by the amount specified here, then prefer the
# key cache method.  This is mainly used to force long character keys in
# large tables to use the slower key cache method to create the index.
myisam_sort_buffer_size=30M

# Size of the Key Buffer, used to cache index blocks for MyISAM tables.
# Do not set it larger than 30% of your available memory, as some memory
# is also required by the OS to cache rows. Even if you're not using
# MyISAM tables, you should still set it to 8-64M as it will also be
# used for internal temporary disk tables.
key_buffer_size=64M

# Size of the buffer used for doing full table scans of MyISAM tables.
# Allocated per thread, if a full scan is needed.
read_buffer_size=2M

read_rnd_buffer_size=2M

#*** INNODB Specific options ***
# innodb_data_home_dir=

# Use this option if you have a MySQL server with InnoDB support enabled
# but you do not plan to use it. This will save memory and disk space
# and speed up some things.
# skip-innodb

# If set to 1, InnoDB will flush (fsync) the transaction logs to the
# disk at each commit, which offers full ACID behavior. If you are
# willing to compromise this safety, and you are running small
# transactions, you may set this to 0 or 2 to reduce disk I/O to the
# logs. Value 0 means that the log is only written to the log file and
# the log file flushed to disk approximately once per second. Value 2
# means the log is written to the log file at each commit, but the log
# file is only flushed to disk approximately once per second.
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

# The size of the buffer InnoDB uses for buffering log data. As soon as
# it is full, InnoDB will have to flush it to disk. As it is flushed
# once per second anyway, it does not make sense to have it very large
# (even with long transactions).
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M

# InnoDB, unlike MyISAM, uses a buffer pool to cache both indexes and
# row data. The bigger you set this the less disk I/O is needed to
# access data in tables. On a dedicated database server you may set this
# parameter up to 80% of the machine physical memory size. Do not set it
# too large, though, because competition of the physical memory may
# cause paging in the operating system.  Note that on 32bit systems you
# might be limited to 2-3.5G of user level memory per process, so do not
# set it too high.
innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M

# Size of each log file in a log group. You should set the combined size
# of log files to about 25%-100% of your buffer pool size to avoid
# unneeded buffer pool flush activity on log file overwrite. However,
# note that a larger logfile size will increase the time needed for the
# recovery process.
innodb_log_file_size=48M

# Number of threads allowed inside the InnoDB kernel. The optimal value
# depends highly on the application, hardware as well as the OS
# scheduler properties. A too high value may lead to thread thrashing.
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

# The increment size (in MB) for extending the size of an auto-extend InnoDB system tablespace file when it becomes full.
innodb_autoextend_increment=64

# The number of regions that the InnoDB buffer pool is divided into.
# For systems with buffer pools in the multi-gigabyte range, dividing the buffer pool into separate instances can improve concurrency,
# by reducing contention as different threads read and write to cached pages.
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8

# Determines the number of threads that can enter InnoDB concurrently.
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000

# Specifies how long in milliseconds (ms) a block inserted into the old sublist must stay there after its first access before
# it can be moved to the new sublist.
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000

# It specifies the maximum number of .ibd files that MySQL can keep open at one time. The minimum value is 10.
innodb_open_files=300

# When this variable is enabled, InnoDB updates statistics during metadata statements.
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0

# When innodb_file_per_table is enabled (the default in 5.6.6 and higher), InnoDB stores the data and indexes for each newly created table
# in a separate .ibd file, rather than in the system tablespace.
innodb_file_per_table=1

# Use the following list of values: 0 for crc32, 1 for strict_crc32, 2 for innodb, 3 for strict_innodb, 4 for none, 5 for strict_none.
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0

# The number of outstanding connection requests MySQL can have.
# This option is useful when the main MySQL thread gets many connection requests in a very short time.
# It then takes some time (although very little) for the main thread to check the connection and start a new thread.
# The back_log value indicates how many requests can be stacked during this short time before MySQL momentarily
# stops answering new requests.
# You need to increase this only if you expect a large number of connections in a short period of time.
back_log=80

# If this is set to a nonzero value, all tables are closed every flush_time seconds to free up resources and
# synchronize unflushed data to disk.
# This option is best used only on systems with minimal resources.
flush_time=0

# The minimum size of the buffer that is used for plain index scans, range index scans, and joins that do not use
# indexes and thus perform full table scans.
join_buffer_size=256K

# The maximum size of one packet or any generated or intermediate string, or any parameter sent by the
# mysql_stmt_send_long_data() C API function.
max_allowed_packet=64M

# If more than this many successive connection requests from a host are interrupted without a successful connection,
# the server blocks that host from performing further connections.
max_connect_errors=100

# Changes the number of file descriptors available to mysqld.
# You should try increasing the value of this option if mysqld gives you the error "Too many open files".
open_files_limit=4161

# If you see many sort_merge_passes per second in SHOW GLOBAL STATUS output, you can consider increasing the
# sort_buffer_size value to speed up ORDER BY or GROUP BY operations that cannot be improved with query optimization
# or improved indexing.
sort_buffer_size=256K

# The number of table definitions (from .frm files) that can be stored in the definition cache.
# If you use a large number of tables, you can create a large table definition cache to speed up opening of tables.
# The table definition cache takes less space and does not use file descriptors, unlike the normal table cache.
# The minimum and default values are both 400.
table_definition_cache=1400

# Specify the maximum size of a row-based binary log event, in bytes.
# Rows are grouped into events smaller than this size if possible. The value should be a multiple of 256.
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its master.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_master_info events.
sync_master_info=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, the MySQL server synchronizes its relay log to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log writes to the relay log.
sync_relay_log=10000

# If the value of this variable is greater than 0, a replication slave synchronizes its relay-log.info file to disk.
# (using fdatasync()) after every sync_relay_log_info transactions.
sync_relay_log_info=10000

# Load mysql plugins at start."plugin_x ; plugin_y".
# plugin_load

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server X Protocol will listen on.
loose_mysqlx_port=33060
```

Comment: can you share my.ini or value of **buffer pool** and key buffer size?

Comment: Please share the query you are trying to run and some stats about the tables you are querying.

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size=256M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
i'm not sure what is key buffer size.

Comment: you mysql requires 2+ GB free RAM to start. Please ensure you have 3 GB free memory on you windows else you can reduce innodb_buffer_pool_instances to 4 and try.

Comment: Added mysql my.ini file. please review it and let me what changes need to be applied.

Comment: When innodb_buffer_pool_size <= 1G, innodb_buffer_pool_instances should be only 1.  (But this does not explain the memory problem.)

Comment: Not sure, but MIGHT it be your DataDir path?  In the comment above for the basedir path that has embedded spaces, the path is wrapped in "double quotes"?  MIGHT?? that be causing some headache?

Comment: Can someone share my.ini config settings for 4 GB RAM.